# IF function in spark gives error

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using below code but it gives error.Kindly guide.

```
val a = Seq(
  ("ram,shyam,hari",12,10),
  ("shyam,ram,hari",3,5)
).toDF("name","id","dt")
  .withColumn("newcol",if($"id">$"dt",0,1))
  .show()
```

Error is as follows,

> :14: error: ')' expected but ',' found.
>            .withColumn("newcol",if($"id">$"dt",0,1)).show()

Answer (score 1):

You need `when.otherwise`:

```
val df = Seq(("ram,shyam,hari",12,10),("shyam,ram,hari",3,5)).toDF("name","id","dt")

df.withColumn("newcol", when($"id" > $"dt", 0).otherwise(1)).show
//+--------------+---+---+------+
//|          name| id| dt|newcol|
//+--------------+---+---+------+
//|ram,shyam,hari| 12| 10|     0|
//|shyam,ram,hari|  3|  5|     1|
//+--------------+---+---+------+
```

Or you can cast the comparison result to *int*:

```
df.withColumn("newcol", ($"id" <= $"dt").cast("int")).show
//+--------------+---+---+------+
//|          name| id| dt|newcol|
//+--------------+---+---+------+
//|ram,shyam,hari| 12| 10|     0|
//|shyam,ram,hari|  3|  5|     1|
//+--------------+---+---+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Use when / otherwis:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.when

df.withColumn("newcol", when($"id" > $"dt", 0).otherwise(1))
```

Comment: Dear All thank you for your answers,actually I know how to achieve by other methods.My question is why it is not done by specifically by 'if' function which is provided by spark.